# Apply different decorators based on a condition

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-decorators, parameterized-unit-test, nose-parameterized

I'm using unittest and nose-parametarized, and want to apply different decorators to a test based on a condition.

I have a test and I want to skip `unittest.skip` the test or execute it `@parameterized.expand(args)`based on the arguments passed to args.

I think I need to have another decorator which applies proper decorator to the test , but now sure how.

pseudo code could be something like this :

```
@validate_data(args)
    def test(args):
    ...
```

where `@validate_data(args)` is a decorator which applies `unittest.skip` if args ==None or `@parameterized.expand(args)`otherwise

Any comments/suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A decorator can also be called as a function. `@decorator` is equivalent to `decorator(func)` and `@decorator(args)` to `decorator(args)(func)`. So you could return the value of those function returns conditionally in your decorator. Here is an example below:

```
def parameterized_or_skip(args=None):
    if args:
        return parameterized.expand(args)
    return unittest.skip(reason='No args')

...

@parameterized_or_skip(args)
def my_testcase(self, a, b):
    pass
```

Comment: Because `parameterized.expand` does nasty `inspect.stack` magic, you'll need to return  a function which will be called from the class' definition and not inside another function. I've updated your answer so it should work.

Comment: @DavidWolever, ah! thanks. I didnt know what that function did :)